# What does "Get a total of 5 hits in StreetSmash" mean?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In Super Smash Bros for 3DS there's a "Get a total of 5 hits in StreetSmash" challenge. However, I can't figure out what is needed to complete it. What does it mean?

I've tried killing 12 opponents which would definitely be 5+ hits, and hitting the enemy puck by moving into them 4 times and then doing dodge + hit combo on a 1v1 since it's really hard to do the charge hit 4 times w/o killing them, but I have yet to beat the challenge.

Comment: Maybe it means "StreetPass hits", i.e. "StreetPass with 5 other players". Not posting as an answer until it can be confirmed.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as Toomai, but it could also just be that it doesn't count practice mode.

Comment: It does not count practice mode, it definitely wants you to streetpass 5 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be that you have to get 5 hits on x number of people streetpassed, rather than number of people. For example, I street passed with one person two days ago and killed him in < 5 hits, but then streetpassed with two people yesterday and killed them both and unlocked the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The game wants you to streetpass 5 people with Smash. I just achieved this challenge yesterday.